# Laplace transforms of a differential equation

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the following differentual equation $y'+4y=11t^7$ with the inital condition $y(0)=3$

I then have to calculate the Laplace transform of $y(t)$

I did the laplace tranform of $y(t)=11t^7$ which gave me the answer $\frac{55440}{s^8}$

I just want to make sure I have done this correctly or if I have selected the wrong value for $y(t)$

Comment: You do need the Laplace transform of the right side, but then you need to relate the Laplace transform of the left side to the Laplace transform of $y$. The two are not simply the same thing.

Comment: @Ian I did the laplace transform of the leftt side and related it to the right side and got (55440+3s^8)/(s^8(s+4)) Is this correct and therefore the laplace transform of y(t)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Laplace transform we have
$$
\mathcal{L}(y')+\mathcal{L}(4y)=\mathcal{L}(11t^7).
$$
Then
$$
s\mathcal{L}(y)-y(0)+4\mathcal{L}(y)=11\frac{7!}{s^{8}}.
$$
Applying the initial condition we have
$$
(s+4)\mathcal{L}(y)=11\frac{7!}{s^{8}}+3.
$$